# Javascript locale string comparison with String.prototype.valueOf

Tags: javascript, locale, string-comparison

I have the following example:

```js
class MyClass {
  constructor(name) {
    this.name = name;
  }

  toString() {
    return this.name;
  }

  valueOf() {
    return this.name;
  }
}

const list = [new MyClass("b"), new MyClass("ä")];

list.sort();
console.log(list.join());

list.sort(new Intl.Collator('de').compare);
console.log(list.join());
```

Here, the `Collator` is required to get the correct sort order, but I want to get rid of it and I want to be able to compare instances of `MyClass` with a simple `myClass1 < myClass2`. This should theoretically be possible by changing the `valueOf` function.

My question now is, is there any JavaScript built-in way to get a "locale" value of a string (similar to `Intl.Collator` or `localeCompare`) that I can return in my `valueOf` function to get the order right?

Comment: That would be a real magic value, as you need to list `ä`, and at the same time `ä` should act like `a`.

Comment: In theory it might be possible, but there is nothing like "*a "locale" value of a string*" - a collation does alter the comparison algorithm, not produce two new strings that could be compared with the normal algorithm.

Comment: I did not really expect it, but I thought that there must be a lookup table or an order stored for each locale somewhere in the browser. So this could be made accessible (e.g. something like `string.localeCharValueAt("de")`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is no such info. Basically, unless you use Intl with specified locale directly (as with `Intl.Collator`) or indirectly (as with `localeCompare`), you will compare codepoints based on browser implementation of strings which is, most likely, by UTF-16 code points.